# backing up Git repository to S3 with SSH

Tags: git, ssh, amazon-s3

I am trying to determine best practices for backing up a Git repo to S3 with SSH on OS X. Can anyone recommend software for doing so?

Comment: This is off-topic because it is a request for recommendations. That said, why not just `git pull` and use the AWS CLI tool to copy the files to S3?

Comment: Why don't you use a hosted git repository? It would probably be easier and give you more useful feature than just a backup. If you want a free private repo you can use bitbucket or gitlab instead of github

Comment: @jfadich I plan on backing up significant amounts of data, wasn't aware that the Bitbucket free private repo would accommodate it. Thanks, I'll check it out.

Comment: @EdCottrell (I wasn't aware about product recommendations, will abide by that in the future). Thanks for recommending CLI.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) tool for this:

```
mc mirror /path/gitrepo https://<bucket>.s3.amazonaws.com/gitrepo
```

If you make changes to the local repository you can run the mirror command again so that it can sync the changed files to S3.